# How can I configure my firebase config to access the firebase emulator functions endpoint?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-tools

Prerequisites:

- Firebase SDK: ^7.21.1

I'd like to connect my Vue.js Frontend with my local firebase functions emulator. The emulator is located at `localhost:5001`. I have a hard time figuring out what configuration properties I have to set to access the emulator endpoint.

Here is my current configuration:

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCKvB9ZluNGOP4s4r8igflwuK-9WVsoThg",
  authDomain: "company-29f5c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://company-29f5c.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "company-bar",
  storageBucket: "company-29f5c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1051704079600",
  appId: "1:1051704079600:web:f99d362c43b87346",
  notificationWebhookUrl: "http://localhost:5001/company-dev/us-central1/notificationsMixpanelWebhook",
  cloudFunctionBaseUrl: "http://localhost:5001/company-dev/us-central1",
};
```

I started changing the `cloudFunctionBaseUrl` since it kind of was obvious for me to use this property to change the functions endpoint url. As you can see I set it to `localhost:5001/...`. However the url being used in my app still was calling this url:

```
https://us-central1-company-bar.cloudfunctions.net
```

I figured out that the url is being composed by the `projectId` property of the configuration. The `cloudFunctionBaseUrl` therefore is not overwriting it at all.

How can I now change the composed url

```
https://us-central1-company-bar.cloudfunctions.net
```

to

```
http://localhost:5001/company-dev/us-central1
```

I expect that there is some kind of configuration flag like `enableEmulator` or something like that but could not find any hint in the docs for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in thinking there's a function, its called `useEmulator`. You have to call it for each part of firebase you want to emulate as far as I'm aware.

If you want to make functions use the emulator you can do something like the following:

```
firebase.functions().useEmulator('localhost', 5001);
```

After the `firebase.initializeApp` call.

More information can be found on the official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#

Comment: It's like going backwards. Previous implementation worked both on emulators and production environment. God, I hate Firebase - I only use it bc it's already implemented, but every single update HAS TO crash something. Today I have to waste time on this: `functions.config()` to make if compatible with the latest functions version...fml

Comment: And here docs are not even updated: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#use_functionsconfig_to_access_environment_configuration_in_a_function dafaq